# Difference between "1.*" and "1.x" in composer require

Tags: composer-php

When requiring packages in composer.json file, what is the difference between:

```
"require": {
    "SomePackage": "1.*"
}
```

and

```
"require": {
    "SomePackage": "1.x"
}
```

or are they both the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the source code](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/4ecdbf89c4a3d1e5dfe73c57e3202a5e2a18c87e/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionParser.php):

```
325.   // match wildcard constraints
326.   if (preg_match('{^(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?\.[x*]$}', $constraint, $matches)) {
                                                         ^^
```

You can see in this regexp that `x` is indeed an [undocumented](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions) alias to `*`.